# Not able to set webhook in facebook rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-webhooks

Hello I am using gem for facebook-messenger

```
# Gemfile
...
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'facebook-messenger'
...
```

and then I had need to setup webhook url while setting webhook url I am facing given error
[image]

I am following [facebook-messenger-description](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/fb-messenger-bot/) .
I rails console it gives following

> Started GET
>   "/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1159185798&hub.verify_token=my_verify_token"
>   for 2a03:2880:2130:cfed:face:b00c:0:8000 at 2017-07-31 17:02:14 +0530
>   Cannot render console from 2a03:2880:2130:cfed:face:b00c:0:8000!
>   Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

Please guide me how to solve this error.

Comment: Your webhook URL has obviously answered with an HTML document instead of the expected challenge value. Could f.e. be the code of one of the default error documents ... But only you can find out what is actually happening, only you have access to the system. So start checking relevant log files, and debugging ...

Comment: I fetch follwoing in my rails console Started GET "/?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1159185798&hub.verify_token=my_verify_token" for 2a03:2880:2130:cfed:face:b00c:0:8000 at 2017-07-31 17:02:14 +0530
Cannot render console from 2a03:2880:2130:cfed:face:b00c:0:8000! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

Answer (score 0):

What is the route of your bot? I Implemented messenger rails here and the default route is https://myurl/bot. I think the error is the return for your main page that come as html.